# why do I have a error 404 with nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to reverse proxy my muximux and sonarr apps
I started with a simple conf :

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name media.mydomain.com;

  location / {
      # reverse to muximux
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8010/;
  }

  location /sonarr {
      # reverse to sonar
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8989/;
  }
}
```

It is working for muximux but for sonar I have an error 404 but the url seems to be correct http://media.mydomain.com/login?returnUrl=

So what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you tried commenting Muximux (temporary disable it for the test) ! follow their guidelines https://github.com/Sonarr/Sonarr/wiki/Reverse-Proxy...  If so may be it's an IPV6 or SSL  issue... Try to comment listen [::]:80; to test it ! It could be conflicting with  some default.conf directive... Do you use certbot?

Comment: Hello, tried to comment the ipv6 argument ans added all the proxy headers like described in the tutorial but I still have the 404 error. And no, I do not use Cerbot.

Comment: On server, using ssh, can you check if your app is running on the background ? Any specific firewall issue... still not clear :) Can you try?  In sonarr config : [<BindAddress>127.0.0.1</BindAddress>] and in nginx conf add to sonarr location bloc [proxy_set_header Host 127.0.0.1; ] and replace localhost by 127.0.0.1